# Short story about moth aliens invading Earth; a human soldier tries to blow up an alien hive but is transformed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

Decades ago (this was in the late 1990s-before 2004, but most likely written much earlier), in some science fiction anthology or other, I remember reading a short story in which moth-aliens took over large parts of Earth, set up hives, sort of thing. A human soldier enters a city which turned into a hive; the soldier had a bomb which was going to be used to blow up the hive.

The only thing I'm 100% certain of is the ending: the mission fails for whatever reason, and he ends up transformed into a female moth-alien himself.

Comment: Some similarities here with Bruce Sterling's "[Swarm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_(novelette))" but that isn't a tale of an invasion of Earth, it takes place on an asteroid in space.

Comment: I'm sure I remember this, and it was from one of the "New Wave" anthologies like "New Writings in British SF" or something similar, but I cannot put my finger on it.

Comment: @JohnRennie I've googled the "England Swings SF" anthology, but can't find anything promising.

Comment: It's got some elements in common with ["A Storm of Wings"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/304254.A_Storm_of_Wings) by M. John Harrison, but I don't think that's the one.

Comment: Regarding "A Storm of Wings" - I've found one section which has quite a bit more in common - could you look at the section headed "Hornwrack the Kamikaze" in [this article](https://atseajournal.com/potboiler-university/viriconium/)?

Comment: [This blog post](http://ajaggedorbit.blogspot.com/2021/01/m-john-harrsion-pastel-city-and-storm.html) implies that the section in my last comment may have taken place at the end of the book. If so, I'm starting to suspect that the short story you read was an extract from "Storm of Wings" and am considering writing an answer instead of these comments - but I just can't be sure yet.

Comment: @JohnRennie Is it possible you're actually remembering a book *about* New Wave SF, that might have quoted extracts from this story in one of the essays?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I have "A Storm of Wings" and it doesn't have any parts that match the description in the question. If my memory is reliable (and it was getting on for 50 years ago) the story I remember was definitely a short story in a new wave anthology, not part of a novel.